# LED strip 12V powered from powerbank

Tags: led

I have LED strip 12V.

https://hadex.cz/k043a-led-pasek-12mm-hlinikovy-bily-teply-72x-led5730m-ip20-delka-1m/.

I tried power from this powerbank (USB cabel cut, black `-` and red `+` wire), but nothing.

https://www.planeo.cz/katalog/1277989-yenkee-ypb-1030-power-bank.html

I wanna buy/try this powerbank?

https://www.datart.cz/powerbanka-emos-alphaq-10-10000-mah-cerna-1613052400.html#moreDescription

***Question 1***

Am I understanding will, that problem is that `Yankee` powerbank have output only 5V?

***Question 2***

If I will try `Emos` powerbank, will it work with LED? Have it 12V output?

Comment: Yes, your problem is that the Yankee powerbank only supplies 5V. No, the Emos powerbank will not work, it is also a 5V supply. Anything that can charge a smartphone is a safe bet to be 5V and thus will not work for you.

Comment: USB power is 5V. With the relatively newer USB PD standard it's possible to upgrade to 9V, 12V or 20V, but only if the charger, cable and device all negotiate to allow it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1.The issue is that the Yankee power bank you mentioned has an output of 5V, which is not sufficient to power your LED strip that requires 12V.

2.The Emos Alphaq 10 with a capacity of 10,000mAh, does not have a specified 12V output. It typically provides the standard USB output of 5V. Therefore, it may not be suitable for powering your 12V LED strip. You would need a power bank with a 12V output or use a different power source capable of supplying the required 12V for your LED strip.

Comment: OK, thanks, I thought. Can you send me some example of powerbank which have 12V output for sure? Thanks.

Comment: @StanislavHosek product recommendations are off-topic for this site. However, it is very simple to find the correct power bank here. Your LED strip consumes 14.4W of power at a 12V supply level. Power = voltage * current, therefore you need to find a powerbank that specifies that it provides 12V **and** supplies at least 1.25 amps. If you are using a battery powerbank instead of a wall-powered one, than be aware - the LED strips will consume 1250mAh every hour, so for example a 2500mAh powerbank will last 2 hours before needing to recharge, a 10000mAh bank will last 8 hours, and so on.

Comment: @InBedded16 Great answer! Thank you. So voltage must be minimal 12V in every case? I am asking, because EMOS powerbank which is linked in my question has 18W (more then 14.4W), but only 5V. So this powerbank is possible to use? https://powerbanky.heureka.cz/baseus-ppjl010001/#specifikace/

Comment: @StanislavHosek Voltage should be exactly 12V not just minimally 12V. Current and power are the specs that have minimal requirements but can be higher. You are correct that a 5V power supply, even one that can provide 18W, will not work. I would strongly recommend finding a Youtube tutorial or article that gives you an overview of how these characteristics work.

Answer (score 0):

One of such power banks is MAXOAK Laptop Power Bank 185Wh/50000mAh. But I can see it is no longer available in Amazon.